# How to put the value of keys in the right spot on excel (Dict)?

Tags: python, dictionary, openpyxl

I am trying to build an excel sheet with my meals.
I was able to build the basics but when I wanted that for each Ingredient with his grams the problem started.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

data = {
    "Meal 1": {
        "Eggs": "140g",
        "Cheese": "200g",
        "Salad": "200g",
        "Avocado": "150g"
    },
    "Meal 2": {
        "Snake": "50g",
        "Coffee": "250g",
    },
    "Meal 3": {
        "Rice": "300g",
        "Meat": "200g",
        "Vagtables": "150g",

    },
    "Meal 4": {
        "Fruit": "150g",
    },
    "Meal 5": {
        "Eggs": "140g",
        "Cheese": "200g",
        "Tuna": "250g",
        "Avocado": "150g"
    }
}

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb['Sheet']
ws.title = 'Ordinary Meal Day'
headings = ["Eggs","Cheese","Salad","Avocado","Snake","Coffee","Rice","Meat","Vagtables","Fruit","Tuna"]
ws.append(headings)
for Meals in data:
    Ingredients = list(data[Meals].values())
    ws.append([Meals] + list(Ingredients))


wb.save('Meals.xlsx')
```

on excel the grams of the ingredients are not in the correct location.
Now, I thought about a solution that I will need to create a loop and if statement to compare for the name of the ingredient but I am not sure if this is the greatest idea.

Answer (score 1):

If using pandas is a possibility, it's pretty straight forward:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

then you get:

|  | Meal 1 | Meal 2 | Meal 3 | Meal 4 | Meal 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Eggs | 140g | nan | nan | nan | 140g |
| Cheese | 200g | nan | nan | nan | 200g |
| Salad | 200g | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| Avocado | 150g | nan | nan | nan | 150g |
| Snake | nan | 50g | nan | nan | nan |
| Coffee | nan | 250g | nan | nan | nan |
| Rice | nan | nan | 300g | nan | nan |
| Meat | nan | nan | 200g | nan | nan |
| Vagtables | nan | nan | 150g | nan | nan |
| Fruit | nan | nan | nan | 150g | nan |
| Tuna | nan | nan | nan | nan | 250g |

and you can just send to an excel file:

```
df.to_excel('meals.xlsx')
```

or if you want a wide table you can just transpose the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
```

|  | Eggs | Cheese | Salad | Avocado | Snake | Coffee | Rice | Meat | Vagtables | Fruit | Tuna |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Meal 1 | 140g | 200g | 200g | 150g | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| Meal 2 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 50g | 250g | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| Meal 3 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 300g | 200g | 150g | nan | nan |
| Meal 4 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 150g | nan |
| Meal 5 | 140g | 200g | nan | 150g | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 250g |

and again to excel:

```
df.to_excel('meals_wide.xlsx')
```